REPT function in Excel
Please I need excel to repeat text in a cell 2x
That is REPT(text, 2)
IF the text is not repeated, but if it is already repeated 2x, it should not and leave it that way.
I tried using this formular
=IF(B2=REPT(B2,1), B2=REPT(B2,2), B2=B2)
It gives me False, then 0 gives me true.
Excel formula or VBA would be greatly appreciated.

=LET(v,B2,x,LEFT(v,LEN(v)/2),IF(v=x&x,v,v&v))

For any cell not B2:
=IF(LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)/2)=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)/2),B2,REPT(B2,2))

This formula allows any symbol at the center of B2 (like xxxYxxx). To avoid this effect, use modified Tim's formula:
=IF(B2=REPT(LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)/2),2),B2,REPT(B2,2))


Pay attention at the additional information I put recently.

You could try, if REGEXTEST() is available to you:
=REPT(B2,2-REGEXTEST(B2,"^(.+)\1$"))

Or:
=REGEXREPLACE(B2,"^(.+?)\1?+$","$1$1")

